# Wrap javascript API?

Tags: javascript, api, architecture, asp.net-web-api

We are looking for your input regarding architectural design of a Javascript API and a .Net (Rest) API.

Background
We are building an enterprise solution with several different channels (Site, App etc) that are consuming data through a service layer, or API. The API is on one hand a .Net WebAPI that are communicating with the business layer but we are also thinking of wrapping external Javascript services (Communication with Google Maps, Google Analytics, Social Login etc) in some sort of API, or maybe SDK. The idea is to have the possibility to quick change components in the Javascript Library (Replace Social Login Provider with someone else).

What is your ideas regarding the Javascript? Should that just be a SDK that wraps other libraries?

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here. This question should be asked in programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on how much control you want to give to your client side development groups. If the UI development group is faster (and on different release schedules) than the group that manages this SDK, then the SDK will just get in the way (unless they are in lock step with the UI group). It would be better to just give them access to the server side APIs then let me compose the page as they see fit.